# Reevaluar el ancho de una columna DataGrid en WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, mvvm

hace poco tiempo trabajo en WPF con MVVM, y se me está planteando el siguiente problema..

Tengo un `DataGrid` sencillo bindeado a un `ObservableCollection`

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Lista}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">    
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Código" Binding="{Binding Path=Codigo}" Width="*"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Título" Binding="{Binding Path=Titulo}" Width="Auto"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Marca" Binding="{Binding Path=Marca}" Width="Auto" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Modelo" Binding="{Binding Path=Modelo}" Width="Auto"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

El DataGrid funciona y se bindea correctamente, el tema, es que lo lleno en tiempo de ejecución basado en un código, y lo que pasa es lo siguiente:

Al iniciar el formulario, el ancho de cada columna, véase los `*` y `auto` se aplican sólo basados en la cabecera, como se ve en esta imágen

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El asunto, es, que ahora, información se añade a mi `ObservableCollection`.. y el ancho de las columnas queda fijo, por lo que se ve así

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El asunto es, es posible hacer que el ancho relativo vuelva a calcularse cuando se añade una fila?

O poder forzarlo mediante el uso de algún evento?

¿Existe alguna solución a esta problemática?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Terminé solucionando mi problema haciendo uso del evento [`TargetUpdated`](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.windows.frameworkelement.targetupdated?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DES-ES%26k%3Dk(System.Windows.FrameworkElement.TargetUpdated);k(VS.XamlEditor);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.6.1)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=netframework-4.8) y estableciendo [`NotifyOnTargetUpdated`](http://NotifyOnTargetUpdated) en `True` para las columnas que deben redimensionarse al llegar nuevo contenido

Por lo que el xaml quedó así

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Lista}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
TargetUpdated="DataGrid_OnTargetUpdated">    
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Código" Binding="{Binding Path=Codigo}" Width="*"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Título" Binding="{Binding Path=Titulo, NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True}" Width="Auto"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Marca" Binding="{Binding Path=Marca, NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True}" Width="Auto" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Modelo" Binding="{Binding Path=Modelo, NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True}" Width="Auto"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

y tuve que controlar el evento en el Code behind

```
private void DataGrid_OnTargetUpdated(object sender, DataTransferEventArgs e)     
{
    //Obtengo el datagrid que llama
    var dg = (DataGrid)sender;
    //Seteo el ancho de la columna que ocupa el ''resto'' del espacio
    dg.Columns[0].Width = 0;
    //Actualizo
    dg.UpdateLayout();
    //Luego vuelvo a setear el ancho relativo.
    dg.Columns[0].Width = new DataGridLength(1,DataGridLengthUnitType.Star);
}
```

Lamentablemente no encontré solución sin tocar code behind, pero por suerte, de esta manera se soluciona el problema

Answer (score 0):

Si revisamos la documentacion

[Sizing Options in the DataGrid Control](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/controls/sizing-options-in-the-datagrid-control)

veras que existe `SizeToCells`

intenta usando

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="Título" Binding="{Binding Path=Titulo}" Width="SizeToCells"/>
```

Comment: Gracias por tu tiempo, pero el resultado lamentablemente es el mismo, al agregar filas, el ancho de las columnas no se adapta al ancho del contenido de las nuevas filas :S